# Laravel Commenting System Only Working on most recent Post

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I recently created a commenting system for a blog. When there is one post in the blog, the commenting sytem works fine. However, when there are two posts on the blog, and I comment on the FIRST post, the comment shows up on the SECOND post. Similarily, if I add another post, so there are three posts in my blog, when I comment on the first post, the comment shows up under the third post. In the same situation, when I comment on the second post, the comment shows up under the third post. Here is my code:

```
/index.blade.php

@section('content')

<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

<hr>

@foreach($posts as $post)
    <h3>{{ $post->title}}</h3>
    <p>by {{ $post->user->name }}</p>
    <img src='{{ asset($post->image_path) }}' class="img-responsive" id="blogpic"/>
    <p>{{ Str::words($post->body) }}</p>
    <p><a href="{{ action('BlogController@show', $post->id) }}">Read More...</a></p>

    <hr>

    {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'CommentController@newComment')) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('post_id', $post->id) }}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
    {{ Form::text('body', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
    {{ Form::submit('Post', array('class'=>'btn btn-info')) }}
        </div>
    </div>



        <br>

    @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
    <div class="comment">
        <p><span class="bold">{{ $comment->user->name }}</span>: {{ $comment->body }}</p>
    </div>

    @endforeach

@endforeach

</div>

  @stop
```

Here is my new comment controller:

```
    public function newComment()
{
    $comment = New Comment();
    $comment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->post_id = $post_id = Input::get('post_id');
    $comment->body = Input::get('body');

    Post::find($post_id)->comments()->save($comment);

    return Redirect::action('BlogController@index');
}
```

I am pretty sure the problem is in my index file, and I can provide more code if needed. My comment only seems to get the most recent id in this line

```
 {{ Form::hidden('post_id', $post->id) }}
```

What could be going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you getting $posts?  It could be a problem with your posts and comments models, and the relationship between them.

Comment: One post has many comments and comments belongs to a post. Comments also belong to users and users have many comments Could any of that be a problem?